# ra-postgraphile: Intercept the error api response

Tags: error-handling, react-admin, postgraphile

I am using ra-postgraphile as dataprovider for react-admin project and i need to intercept the error api response. Is there any error object or function available for that? if yes, Can I get a documentation.

Also posted an issue in [ra-postgraphile repo](https://github.com/BowlingX/ra-postgraphile/issues/27).

> Source Code

```js
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: Config.postgraphileUrl
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => ({
  headers: {
    ...headers,
    authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}));

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const dataProvider = await pgDataProvider(client);
    setDataProvider(() => dataProvider);
  })();
}, []);
```